# Video does not play in app

Tags: swift, video, avplayer, swift4, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an app where when the user selects a button it shows a video.  The code appears to be working as the video player loads.  I've also modified the NSAppTransportSecurity settings to  include NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.  I've hardcoded several videos to see if there was an issue with my specific video but none will work.  Here is the code, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let destination = segue.destination as! AVPlayerViewController
        let url = URL(string:
            "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov")

        if let movieURL = url {
            destination.player = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

        player.play()
    }
```

Comment: Why is `prepare(for segue:)` nested in your `IBAction`?  You need need to perform a segue from the `IBAction`, and then move your `prepare(for segue:)` function into the `UIViewController` subclass scope.

Comment: Thanks JAL, you're right it's not needed as the player still loaded with it not there.  Unfortunately though the video itself still does not play either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this works fine,

```
func playVideo() {

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

    player.play()

}
```